# Ionic 4 Angular: Uncaught ReferenceError: dismissModal is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick (BUT function IS defined!)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

> **Error:**
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: dismissModal is not defined
>       at HTMLElement.onclick

**Match-Summary-Modal.component.html**

```
<ion-header translucent>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Match Summary</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button onclick="dismissModal()">Return to Queue Page</ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content>This match you had a score of {{score}}</ion-card-content>
    <ion-card-content>And a place of {{place}} out of {{playerCount}} players</ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

**Match-Summary-Modal.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-match-summary-modal',
  templateUrl: './match-summary-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./match-summary-modal.component.scss'],
})
export class MatchSummaryModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() score: number;
  @Input() place: number;
  @Input() playerCount: number;


  constructor(private modalController: ModalController) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {}

  async dismissModal() {
    this.modalController.dismiss()
  }

}
```

**GameNetworkService.ts**
(somewhere within the service, with modalController injected)

```
this.lobbyServerSocket.on('match-summary', async (summarydata) => {
        let modal = await this.modalController.create({
          component: MatchSummaryModalComponent,
          componentProps: {
            score: summarydata.score,
            place: summarydata.place,
            playerCount: summarydata.playerCount
          }
        })
        await modal.present()
        this.lobbyServerSocket.disconnect(true)
        this.lobbyServerSocket = null;
      })
```

**Question**
When `dismissModal()` is clearly defined within MatchSummaryModal, 
why is angular/ionic unable to find the `dismissModal()` method that is quite clearly called & contained within the component when the button is clicked?

Additionally, what do I need to do to get the intended functionality? (Which is to make the modal dismiss itself on button click)

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be

```
<ion-button (click)="dismissModal()">Return to Queue Page</ion-button>
```

instead of

```
<ion-button onclick="dismissModal()">Return to Queue Page</ion-button>
```

Comment: Just learning angular/ionic, appreciate feedback. Not sure why I utilized it that way considering the reset of my app uses (click) :)

Comment: Same mistake for me, i just copied/past the source of the exemple of this page https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal from the DevTool Inspector (bad idea I know)